# Google Sheet Custom Formula to run automatically when another cell is populated with value

Tags: google-sheets

I can not get my head around how to write this formula.

I am trying to get the value of sold item and then run  function that calculate the ebay fee, paypal fee and profit and display the result in theirs cells .

Can i have this function run automatically as I enter new row and as soon as value for sold is given it calculates the rest for me ?

Here is a picture of my spreed sheet if that helps

[image: MY Google Sheet]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

Write the cost function (e.g. `=C2*15%` in `D2`) so that you are happy with the calculation. Then surround that with a conditional: `=IF(C2="","",[your calculation])`. You can fill that formula all the way down and it will only display when a value is present in the respective row in column `C`.

Explanation: The `C2=""` part just looks to see if `C2` is empty.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide the whole code ? never done this before ...

Comment: Then you will have to provide the prices. I don't know the shopping cost for example.

Comment: i can do the math as long as i know how to write the code. and is it auto or i need to call the function on every row myself manually ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to start here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Q2C9MB-YH4